# S3 listObjects recursively node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ecmascript-6

I want to recursively get all the files in an S3 bucket folder.
I want to achieve the same behaviour as the `ls -R` command in Linux.

Here's an illustration

```
my_folder
  |_abc
  | |_abc_file.txt
  | |_xyz
  |   |_xyz_file.txt
  |
  |_file.txt
```

Considering the above directory structure. if I do

```
 const data = await s3.listObjectsV2({
    Prefix: 'my_folder/',
    Bucket: bucket,
    Delimiter: `/`,
}).promise();
```

Currently, I get the following `data`:

```
-CommonPrefixes: ["abc"]
-Contents:["file.txt"]
```

The expected behaviour is:

```
- Contents: ["abc/abc_file.txt", "abc/xyz/xyz_file.txt", "file.txt"]
```

I tried using **ES6 generator functions** and **recursive functions** to solve this problem and end up with a lot of messed up code.

I am using S3 node SDK

Comment: S3 is a [flat object store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html), it doesn't known any "folders" (and you cannot really create "empty folders") and there is no recursion. Your code should work. How are you actually storing this structure? What is the object stored at `my_folder_abc`?

Comment: ok ignore the empty folder. but still getting the files recursively is a challenge

Comment: when I do listObjects() in "my_folder" then I only get "abc" not the file inside "abc"

Comment: Again, what is the exact (full) key of that object?

Comment: "my_folder" is at the root of the bucket

Comment: That's interesting. Normally I only see `CommonPrefixes` come back when a `Delimiter` is provided. If you do _not_ specify a Prefix, does everything come back as expected? How about adding a slash to the end of the Prefix?

Comment: slash is already there at the end of the folder name, delimiter is also there. tried your suggested solution but nothing worked.

Comment: @ZainulAbideen Since you want *all* the files, not just the top level, you should just not use the [`delimiter` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html) at all! See also https://realguess.net/2014/05/24/amazon-s3-delimiter-and-prefix/

Comment: Cool! removing the Delimiter parameter worked. Thank you so much.
Can you please post it as an answer?  Others will also be benefitted from this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon S3 is a flat object storage system that does not use directories. Instead, the Key (filename) of an object includes the full path of the object. Directories magically 'appear' based on the paths of existing objects, and can later disappear when there are no objects in that path.

A `CommonPrefix` is the Amazon S3-equivalent of showing a sub-directory.

When calling `ListObjects()` with a `Delimiter` parameter (eg `Delimiter='/'`), a list of subdirectories is returned in the `CommonPrefixes` field. This allows recursion through directories much like traditional storage systems. If you remove this parameter, all objects with the given Prefix will be returned, rather than just the 'current directory'.

Comment: the key part is this: **If you remove this parameter, all objects with the given Prefix will be returned, rather than just the 'current directory**